# Find the asymptotic distribution of ${\theta}_{MLE} =\frac{-n}{\sum _{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(X_i)}-1$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

> We are given $f(x|\theta) = (\theta  + 1)x^{\theta} , \hspace{7mm} 0<x<1, \theta > -1.$
>
> By considering the asymptotic distribution  of $\frac{1}{\theta_{MLE}+1}$,  find the asymptotic distribution of $\theta_{MLE}$.

**My attempt:**

I have worked out that the MLE to this question is $$\theta _{MLE} = \frac{-n}{\sum _{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(X_i)}-1$$

and I also worked out that $-\ln(X_i)$ $\sim \exp(\frac{1}{\theta + 1})$

Now, $$\frac{1}{\theta_{MLE}+1} = \frac{\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} -\ln(X_i)}{n}$$

I don't know how to proceed from here as the question asks for asymptotic distribution for $\theta_{MLE}$ yet what can I extract from  $\frac{1}{\theta_{MLE}+1}$ ?

How do I compute the asymptotic distribution for a question like this?

Comment: Use central limit theorem on $-\ln X_i$ (the sum you have written should be a finite sum, so $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$ assuming you have a sample of size $n$). That would give you asymptotic distribution of $1/(\theta_{MLE}+1)$. From there, you would need to apply the 'delta method' to get the limiting distribution of $\theta_{MLE}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you know the exact distribution of the MLE, $\hat{\theta}$. Namely, as $-\ln X_i = Y_i$ has an exponential distribution with $\theta+1$, that is 
$$
f_Y(y)=(\theta+1)\exp\{ - y(\theta+1)\}, \quad y>0,
$$
thus $ \sum Y_i $ distributed Gamma with $n$ and $\theta + 1$. So $(\sum Y_i)^{-1}$ has an inverse  Gamma distribution with the same parameters. As such, 
$$
\hat{\theta}_n = n/\sum Y_i - 1 \equiv n\times \mathrm{InvGamma(n,\theta+1) -1}.
$$
For the asymptotic properties define $g(x) = 1/x -1$, thus the MLE is
$$
\hat{\theta}_n = g(\bar{Y}_n) = 1/\bar{Y}_n-1,
$$
by the continuous mapping theorem 
$$
g(\bar{Y}_n) \xrightarrow{P}g(\mathbb{E}Y)=(1/(\theta + 1))^{-1} - 1= \theta,
$$
hence by the CLT
$$
\sqrt{n}( g(\bar{Y}_n) - \theta)\xrightarrow{D} N(0, (g'(\theta))^2/(\theta+1)^2),
$$
where $(g'(\theta))^2 = 1 / \theta ^ 2$.